# How long are requests stored in apache tomcat request queue?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

Is there a timeout setting for requests stored in the apache tomcat request queue? If yes, what is the default value for the embedded tomcat in spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring a web server, it also might be useful to set the server connection timeout. This represents the maximum amount of time the server will wait for the client to make their request after connecting before the connection is closed.
You may specify this property in your application.properties as follows.

```
server.connection-timeout=5s
```